# Typescript extend third-party declaration files

Tags: javascript, typescript, koa

How can I extend third-party declaration files?
for example, I want to extend `Context` from [@types/koa](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/616c84c0e73295a78a94b96276da833dcafe9ea0/types/koa/index.d.ts#L644) and add an extra field(`resource`) to it.
I tried this:

```
// global.d.ts
declare namespace koa {
    interface Context {
        resource: any;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work:

```
error TS2339: Property 'resource' does not exist on type 'Context'.
```

### Update

a simplified version of my code which produces this error:

```
import {Context} from 'koa';
import User from './Models/User';
class Controller {
   async list(ctx: Context) {
        ctx.resources = await User.findAndCountAll();
        ctx.body = ctx.resources.rows;
        ctx.set('X-Total-Count', ctx.resources.count.toString());
        ctx.status = 200;
    }
}
```

> typescript v2.4

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please post a [verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Note that "it doesn't work" is explicitly listed as an insufficient description of a problem.

Comment: Remove `declare`. The namespace has already been declared by the third party library, you are just extending it. And you have to say `export interface <interfaceName>` inside your namespace. [`Docs Here`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces)

Comment: @jcalz Error details has been added

Comment: @mhodges `A 'declare' modifier is required for a top level declaration in a .d.ts file.`

Comment: @mhodges adding export doesn't make any change.

Comment: If @Saravana's answer doesn't fix your problem, please include the code that's producing the error.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to use [module augmentation as described here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
import { Context } from "koa";

declare module "koa" {
    interface Context {
        resource: any;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding this to a separate `*.d.ts` file?

Comment: Yes, It's currently located in global.d.ts, but I have tested with another separate file and nothing changed.

Comment: I tried with the exact same code you are using and it works for me. Can you post something that can be reproduced.

Comment: How do you do this without the "import" so an ambient file remains ambient and doesn't module-up and stop working?

Comment: I expanded the FastifyInstance with this trick. Many thanks