# Typescript: importing an extension file of third-party package

Tags: typescript

I tried to learn from this thread: [Typescript extend third-party declaration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493253/typescript-extend-third-party-declaration-files)
But it's about using 'global.d.ts'

I'm trying to follow the Emotion library guide to define a theme and create an interface for it (https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript).

I created the file 'emotion.d.ts' in my src folder, with the code:

```
import '@emotion/react'

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme {
    color: {
      primary: string
      positive: string
      negative: string
    }
  }
}
```

How should I let Typescript know about this file, so it can extend the Emotion library type declarations?

EDIT: When creating a global.d.ts file in the root folder with the same code, the interface is being recognized, but with that custom file name, it's not

Comment: the name doesn't matter. just stick it in your project root

Comment: That's not true for me unfortunately, when using global.d.ts with the same code everything works, but in a custom file in the project root it doesn't recognize the interface anymore